# Is using "include:_spf.google.com" and MX in SPF records considered duplicate?

Tags: spf

**Situation**

We are using the "mx" action in our spf records where the mx is setup like https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en

And also "include:_spf.google.com"

**Question:**

Is using both: "include:_spf.google.com" and the mx records considered duplicate, ie the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's fine because inbound and outbound servers are not necessarily the same. In the case of a big provider like gmail they likely have entirely separate server farms for inbound and outbound, so you really do want to defer to their records because they are likely to change frequently.

Comment: Don’t you think we can remove the mx record? And that they will naturally include it in the spf records chain?

Comment: If we can verify this or the other I can accept. I think it will help a lot of people.

Comment: It would seem very silly for google to publish an SPF that did not include all of their outbound gmail servers (what your MX would refer to), but I can't guarantee that 100%